# Duration Test data source

Tags: content-testing

I'm currently working on the content tests, and the moment to activate this feature, I discovered that the Objective window, inside the duration section, Sitecore never display any value.

Does anyone knows where I can configure this?

[image]

Comment: is there any console error? or check the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined in `core` database under

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Common/Layouts/Composite/Scheduling/PageSettings
```

Minimum durations are items in

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Common/Layouts/Composite/Scheduling/PageSettings/MinimumDurations
```

folder and maximum durations are items in

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/ContentTesting/Common/Layouts/Composite/Scheduling/PageSettings/MaximumDurations
```

folder.

See the screenshot from `core` database:

[image: content testing minimum and maximum duration settings]

Look like either you have some backend or javascript errors which prevents them from loading on your website or one removed the values from `core` database.

Comment: You're right, Thanks for the help!!!!